# Scope through variables using mutate_at/ ifelse creating new variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this code checking for outliers (pseudo outliers in this data -- only 1.25sd plus the mean in this example) using a function but for scaling it up for many variables without specifying each ifelse would there be a way?

```
library(tidyverse)

meanplusd <- function (var){mean(var, na.rm  = TRUE)+(1.25*(sd(var, na.rm  = TRUE)))}

mtcars%>% 
  mutate_at(vars(drat:qsec), .funs = list(meanplus = ~ meanplusd(.))) %>% 
  mutate(outlier_drat = ifelse(drat   > drat_meanplus,1,0),
         outlier_wt   = ifelse(wt     > wt_meanplus,1,0),
         outlier_qsec = ifelse(qsec   > qsec_meanplus ,1,0)) %>%
  filter_at(vars(outlier_drat:outlier_qsec), any_vars (.== 1)) %>% 
  select(-c(drat_meanplus:qsec_meanplus))


mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb outlier_drat outlier_wt outlier_qsec
1 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1            0          0            1
2 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2            0          0            1
3 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4            0          1            0
4 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4            0          1            0
5 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4            0          1            0
6 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2            1          0            0
7 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2            1          0            0
>
```

Open to non-tidyverse ways too for learning purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could determine outliers all in one function:

```
is_outlier <- function(var) {
  as.numeric(var > na.omit(var) %>% {mean(.) + 1.25*sd(.)})
}

mtcars %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(drat:qsec), .funs = list(outlier = ~ is_outlier(.))) %>%
  filter_at(vars(drat_outlier:qsec_outlier), any_vars (.== 1))

   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb drat_outlier wt_outlier qsec_outlier
1 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1            0          0            1
2 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2            0          0            1
3 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4            0          1            0
4 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4            0          1            0
5 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4            0          1            0
6 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2            1          0            0
7 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2            1          0            0
```

Comment: even though this answer is great and the accepted one, I'm still curious to know in general how to apply the ifelse to many vars and create new ones all at once, hmmm...

Comment: Why don't you just use another `mutate_at` statement with an `ifelse` in the function?

Comment: Thank you thc. `ifelse(var > na.omit(var) %>% {mean(.) + 1.25*sd(.)},1,0)` will work too, but I am a little confused about this: `ifelse(var > var_meanplus,1,0)`--i.e., creating the function outside and referencing the new train of variables by name somehow this way via mutate_at

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to filter the rows you could directly use `filter_at` and apply `meanplusd` function

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% filter_at(vars(drat:qsec), any_vars(. > meanplusd(.)))

#   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#2 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#3 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#4 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#5 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#6 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#7 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
```

Or in base R we can use `sapply` over selected columns and use `rowSums`

```
mtcars[rowSums(sapply(mtcars[5:7], function(x) x > meanplusd(x))) > 0, ]
```

---

However, if you want new columns with the outlier value you can do something like

```
df <- mtcars
cols <- names(df)[5:7]
df[paste0(cols, "_outlier")] <- lapply(mtcars[cols],function(x) +(x > meanplusd(x)))
df[rowSums(df[paste0(cols, "_outlier")]) > 0, ]
```

Comment: Great answers Ronak, these like the previous answer are eye-opening for me, i.e, helpful concepts to build on. many thanks